# Is something wrong on using a BehaviorSubject in an InjectionToken?

Tags: angular

I want to use a `BehaviorSuject` in an `InjectionToken` as the injected value may change and I want to subscribe to those changes.

I've been looking around and I haven't seen any example or usage as I describe so, I'm not sure if injecting an `Observable` instead of a value is a good practice.

Can anyone help me with these doubts?

P.D.: The use case is to provide a Timezone, which most of the time will be a value which won't change, but the user can modify it and I want to update the injected value.

Answer (score 0):

most common solution for the described problem is to use Service with some methods  to set/get data. but really nothing makes it impossible to provide a behaviorSubject

```
export const SubjectToken = new InjectionToken<BehaviorSubject<MyType>>('TheSubject');
export const mySubject = new BehaviorSubject<MyType>(null);
....

providers: [{ 
  provide: SubjectToken,
  useValue: mySubject
}]
```

Comment: can you share in which type of use-case this type of injecting behavior is useful?

Comment: why do you ask this question under the answer? It is just the description of how to achieve the thing that the question asks for

Answer (score -1):

**You can find** working demo here on this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ask4za?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**First,** You have to inject your provider in main app.module.ts.

```
@NgModule({
     ...
     providers: [{ provide: MyValueToken, useValue: new BehaviorSubject('')}]
})
```

**Then, create one token.ts** file in root folder and define `MyValueToken` there and export it.

```
import {InjectionToken} from '@angular/core';
export const MyValueToken = new InjectionToken<string>('');
```

**In your app.component.ts** you have to inject token.. and pass data using `next()` method of behaviorsubject.

```
constructor(@Inject(MyValueToken) private my_value: BehaviorSubject<string>) {
     my_value.next(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);
}
```

**Then, in your any child component** you can get value from behavior-subject like this..

```
constructor(@Inject(MyValueToken) my_value: BehaviorSubject<string>) {
   my_value.subscribe( value => this.title = value)
}
```

Comment: I'm not asking for examples or implementations, I've already have my own working one. What I'm asking for is it to know if it is a good practice or not.

Comment: `I've been looking around and I haven't seen any example or usage as I describe so` in this line of what you are asking for same?, and its never been a problem to use `BehaviorSubject` as `injection token` as long as many component are subscribed to only a single change value and all needed a updated value for the same. This is for simple use-case for simple one value mechanism .